# combine two jquery select statements

Tags: jquery, select, merge

how can i merge the results of two select statments with jquery?

for example i have

```
var previous = $(this).prev('td');
var next = $(this).next('td');
```

how do i then combine the two sets of results into one?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
var all = $.merge(previous, next);
```

Comment: Beware, the first selector (previous) will be modified and content all

Comment: To avoid modifying the first selector...

var result = $.merge($.merge([], previous), next);

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
var all=$(this).prev('td').add( $(this).next('td') );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use empty collection

```
var previous = $(this).prev('td'),
    next = $(this).next('td'),
    buttons = $().add(previous).add(next);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UBnMm/

Alternatively:

```
var buttons = $(this).prev('td').add($(this).next('td'));
```

Comment: *Please* don't use the comma to separate var declarations. It is harder to read, harder to cut-n-paste, error-prone and saves only 3 characters...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't agree with neither one – I use it exactly because it's easier to read, don't care for cut&paste much (after all, any serious editor/IDE can group-tab) and I don't see why this should be error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for $(this).siblings('td')

Comment: *"for example I have"*, said callumander. You gave an answer to given example, not to asked question.